# Regex to find name and id from string like [thename id=432]

Tags: php, regex

I am in need of a regex that can find the brackets from a certain string and extract the value of id from it. E.g.:

```
$string = "Hey how are you, this is [ads id=432] going to be fun!";
```

I need name like `ads` and id like `432`.

And how to replace these brackets with some other value eg `$ads = "ads here";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$regexp = "#\[(?<name>[^\]]+) id=(?<id>[0-9]+)\]#";
```

**exemple**

```
<?php
   $regexp = "#\[(?<name>[^\]]+) id=(?<id>[0-9]+)\]#";
   $string = "Hey how are you, this is [ads id=432] going to be fun!";
   preg_match($regexp, $string, $match);
   print_r($match);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => [ads id=432]
    [name] => ads
    [1] => ads
    [id] => 432
    [2] => 432
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression `(?<=\[ads\s+id=)(\d+?)(?=\])`
if you need somethink like ads use this `` `(?<=\[)(\w+)\s+id=(\d+?)(?=\]) `` name and value into regex groups